# What rational numbers are expressible as "multiple-of-$12$" continued fractions?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, continued-fractions

I need to use a special subclass of continued fraction expansions for a problem I'm studying. Namely, expansions of the form

$$[a_0;a_1;a_2;\dotsc; a_{n}] = a_0+\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_2+\displaystyle\frac{1}{\ddots\displaystyle\frac{1}{a_n}}}}$$
where $a_0,\dotsc, a_{n-1}\in 12\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n\in S\subset\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$, a finite subset of the extended rationals.

This problem is in analogue to the "even continued fraction expansions", which have $a_0,\dotsc, a_{n-1}\in 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n\in\{0,1,\infty\}$. It turns out that the set of even continued fraction expansions is just all of $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$. The proof uses the projectivized congruence level $2$ subgroup ${\rm P}\Gamma(2)$, which is generated by the Möbius transformations
$$A: z\mapsto \frac{z}{-2z+1}\text{ and }B: z\mapsto z+2.$$
I've seen it claimed in various places (but never with proof) that the (left) action of ${\rm P\Gamma}(2) = \langle A, B\rangle$ on $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$ has orbit transversal $\{0,1,\infty\}$, meaning that for each $r/s\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$ there is a word $w\in \langle A,B\rangle$ such that $r/s = w.x$ for some $x\in\{0,1,\infty\}$. Determining an even continued fraction expansion for $r/s$ from there is then simply a matter of decoding the corresponding word $w$.

Now, my questions: is there any hope of a similar result holding in the "multiple-of-$12$" expansion case? Namely, could there be some finite set $S$ such that expansions of that form describe all of $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$? Equivalently, if $G$ is the group generated by the transformations
$$a: z\mapsto z+12, \quad b:z\mapsto -z,\quad c:z\mapsto 1/z,$$
does the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$ have a *finite* orbit transversal? And how would such an orbit transversal be calculated, finite or not?

This seems like a pretty tough/niche problem, so even just pointing me in the direction of some references would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I gave both $b$ and $c$ as valid transformations since I happen to have those symmetries in the context I'm working in, but if one needs to restrict this to just $z\mapsto -1/z$ so that $G$ is a subset of ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$, then that is fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let me first indicate the proof in the case of $P\Gamma(2)$, and then I will go on to explain what goes wrong in the case of your "multiple of $12$" question.

The action of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ on the upper half plane has a [fundamental domain $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481463/transformations-between-the-fundamental-domains-of-eisenstein-series) which is a triangle with three hyperbolic geodesic sides, two finite vertices, and with one vertex "at infinity. Two of the sides are on the respective lines $x=-1/2$ and $x=+1/2$ (dotted orange in [the linked diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481463/transformations-between-the-fundamental-domains-of-eisenstein-series)); the third side is on the circle $z^2=1$ (solid blue in the linked diagram).  This description uniquely determines $D$. The upper half plane is tiled by other fundamental domains, each a translate of $D$ by some element of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, any two of which meet along a common side, a common vertex, or not at all. The ideal vertex of the fundamental domain $D$ is the point $\infty$, and from this fact the proof of the standard continued fraction theorem can be produced.

Generally speaking, for any subgroup $\Gamma < \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, one can produce a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ that is a union of some translates of $D$. The set of translates corresponds 1-to-1 with the left cosets of $\Gamma$ in $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, and in particular the number of translates is equal to the index of $\Gamma$ in $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$.

The key feature of the subgroup $P\Gamma(2) < \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is that it has finite index, in fact the index is equal to $6$. One can demonstrate this by exhibiting a fundamental domain $E$ for $P\Gamma(2)$ that is a union of $6$ translates of $D=D_1$. A picture would be worth a thousand words here, but I'll go with somewhat fewer words and no picture (but with references to [the linked diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481463/transformations-between-the-fundamental-domains-of-eisenstein-series))

Starting with $D=D_1$ itself, let $D_2$ be the image of $D$ under the transformation $z \mapsto z+1$. The union $D_1 \cup D_2$ is a quadrilateral with one ideal vertex at $\infty$ and with the opposite vertex being a finite vertex at the point $p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i$ (in the linked diagram, $p$ is one of the points where three blue segments and three dotted orange segments meet). The stabilizer of the point $p$ in the group $PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is cyclic of order $3$, generated by the transformation $\gamma : z \mapsto \frac{1}{-z+1}$. The other four fundamental domains comprising $E$ are $D_3 = \gamma(D_1)$, $D_4 = \gamma(D_2)$, $D_5=\gamma(D_3)$, $D_6 = \gamma(D_5)$; these are the six fundamental domains which fit around the point $p$. In summary,
$$E = D_1 \cup D_2 \cup D_3 \cup D_4 \cup D_5 \cup D_6
$$
is a fundamental domain for $P\Gamma(2)$. It is bounded by six geodesics lying on the following six hyperbolic lines: the lines $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3}{2}$; the circle $(z+1)^2=1$; the circle $(z-2)^2=1$; the circle $(z-1/3)^2 = 1/9$; and the circle $(z-2/3)^2 = 1/9$. The six vertices of $E$ alternate between three ideal vertices at $0$, $1$ and $\infty$, and three finite vertices.  The edge identifications of $E$ are such that for each of the three ideal vertices $\xi \in \{0,1,\infty\}$, the two sides of $E$ incident to $\xi$ are identified by a parabolic transformation that fixes $\xi$. For example, the transformation $z \mapsto z + 2$ that fixes $\infty$ identifies the side of $E$ on the line $x=0$ with the side on the line $x=2$. The key feature of $E$ that follows from this description is that the quotient is a three-cusped sphere, those three cusps being in one-to-one correpsondence with the three orbits of the action of $P\Gamma(2)$ on $\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$, with orbit transversal equal to the three ideal vertices $0$, $1$, $\infty$ of $E$. From this fact the proof of the "even continued fraction" theorem follows.

---

So, what happens with your "multiple of 12" continued fractions? As suggested at the end of your post, I'll stay in the group $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ and I'll consider its subgroup generated by $z \mapsto z + 12$ and $z \mapsto - \frac{1}{z}$ which I'll denote $\Gamma_{12}$ for lack of a better notation.

The trouble is, the subgroup $\Gamma_{12}$ has infinite index in $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, and what's worse its action on $\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$ has infinitely many orbits. So every orbit transversal is infinite.

In fact it's even worse than that. The action of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ has the property that the orbit $\{\gamma \cdot x \mid \gamma \in \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)\}$ of every $x \in \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is dense; for example, the orbit $\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$ is dense. This property is called *topological minimality*. But the topological behavior of action of $\Gamma_{12}$ on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is at the far extreme from topological minimality: there exists an open interval $U \subset \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $\gamma(U) \cap U = \emptyset$ for every nontrivial $\gamma \in \Gamma_{12}$. So any two numbers $x \ne y \in U \cap (\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\})$ have disjoint orbits. And, of course, $U \cap (\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\})$ is an infinite set; we could construct an orbit tranversal that contains the set $U \cap (\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\})$ as a subset, and so that orbit transversal contains a *dense subset* of $U$.

So the summary is that I don't see any hope for a nice theory of "multiple-of-12" continued fraction expansions of rational numbers, that would generalize the theory of "even continued fractions".

---

A few final words: this answer is informed by the theory of [Fuchsian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group), which are discrete subgroups $\Gamma < \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acting on the upper half plane. Each such $\Gamma$ has a "limit set" which is the unique minimal closed subset $\Lambda \subset \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ on which the restricted action of $\Gamma$ is topologically minimal. There are many equivalent descriptions of $\Lambda$: one of them says that if there is a fundamental domain with an ideal point (a vertex at $\infty$) that maps to a cusp of the quotient, then $\Lambda$ is the closure of the $\Gamma$ orbit of that ideal point. So, for example, the limit sets of the Fuchsian groups $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ and of $P\Gamma(2)$ are both equal to the whole circle $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$.

If the limit set $\Lambda$ is *not* the whole of the circle $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ (as in the group $\Gamma_{12}$), then the action of $\Gamma$ on the open set $(\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}) - \Lambda$ is *properly discontinuous*, implying that each point has an open subset $U$ such that $U$ is disjoint from all but finitely many of its translates $\gamma \cdot U$ ($\gamma \in \Gamma$). This open set $(\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}) - \Lambda$ is called the *domain of discontinuity* of $\Gamma$.

If the domain of discontinuity of a subgroup $\Gamma < \text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is not empty, i.e. if $\Lambda$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, it follows that for each point $x$ in the domain of discontinuity there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and an orbit transversal $T$ of the action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb Q \cup \{\infty\}$ such that $U \cap T$ is a dense subset of $U$.

When thinking about your subgroup $\Gamma(12)$, I could see that its domain of discontinuity of was nonempty, leading to my answer.

---

**Coda: Regarding the domain of discontinuity.** Here's an impressionistic proof that the domain of discontinuity of $\Gamma(12)$ is nonempty.

Consider the invariant tree $T$ of the action of $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, which is the blue tree $T$ in the [linked diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481463/transformations-between-the-fundamental-domains-of-eisenstein-series). The transformation $z \mapsto z + 12$ translates along an "axis" in $T$ which is the uppermost blue bouncy "line" $L$ in the tree $T$, comprised of a bi-infinite concatenation of circular arcs; the action of this translation is to move each circular arc to the $12^{\text{th}}$ circular arc along $L$ to the right. Also, the transformation $z \mapsto -\frac{1}{z}$ fixes the midpoint of one of those circular arcs (that fixed point is, of course, $i \in \mathbb C$). As you translate that bouncy line around by all possible products of those two transformations (which generate a group isomorphic to the free product $\mathbb Z * (\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$), and then take the union of those translates, you obtain a tree $T(12)$ in which any two translates of $L$ are either disjoint or intersect along one blue circular arc. Furthermore, each component of $T - T(12)$ is an infinite tree whose set of accumulation points in $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is an arc. From this description, one sees that $T(12)$ is a proper subtree of $T$ whose set of accumulation points in $\mathbb R \cup \infty$ is a Cantor set, and the complement of that Cantor set is the union of the interiors of the open arcs corresponding to the components of $T \setminus T(12)$. That Cantor set is the limit set of $\Gamma(12)$, and its (nonempty) complement is the domain of discontinuity.

Comment: I think there is a minor typo with $\Gamma < \text{PSL(2,\mathbb Z)}$ in your text near the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! The added background made all this a lot clearer to me, even if my original problem turned out to be intractable.


One small question: You say "there exists an open interval $U$ such that $\gamma(U)\cap U = \emptyset$ for every nontrivial $\gamma\in\Gamma_{12}$." Unless I'm misunderstanding things, this was inferred from your observation that the domain of discontinuity was nonempty. Is there a convenient way to see either of these facts?

Comment: I've added a coda explaining why that domain of discontinuity is nonempty for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the bug fix @HandeBruijn.